# Unlocking iPhone 4

Tags: iphone, unlock

I forgot my passcode to my phone because my friend changed it. I'm not locking it, so I can still use my phone. The computer my phone is backed up on is down right now. Is there any way I can go to the apple store and have them unlock my phone? Or any way to take my passcode off besides resetting it on my computer. That option is not possible right now. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

No. There is no way to bypass the passcode lock on iOS. Either you remember the code/get it from your friend, or you have to restore the iPhone.

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to restore the phone using iTunes on a Mac or PC

To do that, turn off your phone, than plug your phone in (to the computer) while keeping the home button pressed until an iTunes symbol appears on the iPhone's screen. iTunes should "detect a phone in restore mode" and you'll be able to reset your phone.

Apple Article on the topic: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1212?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

Answer (score 1):

If you have a back up from before it was changed you can do a DFU restore then restore back to what it was like before

Comment: Thanks for your answer, M3000! Can you please add more information about how to do a DFU restore? Thanks.